# using the return value of one function as an argument in another function in c++

Tags: c++

I found some related answers but couldn't understand it clearly because the codes were complicated for me.

In this program I used the `dif ()` to find the difference in price then stored  the return value total in variable `difrnc`. Then I used the `difrnc` variable as an argument for the function call

```
inflation=inflan(difrnc,lyp) //(calculates the inflation)
```

Instead of storing the total in variable `difrnc` can I directly use the answer from the function `dif()` as an argument for the function `inflan()` in its definition and how?

Sorry if it is a repeated question it would be great if someone could explain it using this program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double dif(double lp,double cp);//cp= current price,lp= last price, current 
double inflan(double difference,double lastyp);
double cost(double cp,double inrate);

int main()
{
        double lyp,cyp,difrnc,inflation,one_year_cost;  // lyp = last year price,cyp=current year price, 
        for(int i=0;i>=0;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter current years price :";
            cin>>cyp;
            cout<<"Enter last Years price: ";
            cin>>lyp;
            difrnc=dif(lyp,cyp);
            if(difrnc<0)
            {
                cout<<"price decreased by "<<difrnc<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"price increased by "<<difrnc<<endl;
            }
            inflation=inflan(difrnc,lyp);
            one_year_cost=cost(cyp,inflation);
            cout<<one_year_cost<<endl;
        }   
}
    // to find the difference in price
    double dif(double lp,double cp)
    {
        double total;
        total=cp-lp;
        return(total);
    }
    // to find the inflation
    double inflan(double difference,double lastyp)
    {
        double inrate;
        inrate=difference/lastyp;
        return(inrate);
    }
    // to find estimated cost in one year
    double cost(double cp,double inrate)
    {
        double
        totalc=cp+inrate;
        return(totalc);
    }
```

Comment: You can, like `inflation=inflan(dif(lyp,cyp),lyp);`, but you'll call `dif` again. Storing the result in `difrnc` and then use it later seems fine here.

Comment: You may find it helpful to submit the code to the codereview community to get feedback on your usage of C++ if you want that

Comment: WorldSEnder-thanks great help didnt know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can like this `inflatio n = inflan(dif(lyp,cyp),lyp);`

However, since you use the function returned value more than once, it make more sense to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your current issue in your functions you can simplify them by removing their local variables and just simply return the evaluated expression.

For Example: You have this ->

```
double cost( double cp, double inrate ) {
    double totalc = cp + inrate;
    return totalc;
}
```

It is safe and efficient to do this instead:

```
double cost( double cp, double inrate ) {
    return cp + inrate;
}
```

You can do that for any simple function that doesn't go through any loops.

As for your actual issue check out this quick program;

**Sample.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int five() {
    return 5;
}

int ten() {
    return 10;
}

int add( int a, int b ) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {

    std::cout << add( five(), ten() ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Set a break point within the first line of your main function and step through the code line by line while examining your stack calls as well as your local and auto variables to see what is happening on each line of your functions to see the values that are being assigned to each variable.

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything called "Stack variables". And the optimization is not required. Any sane compiler will take care of the register allocation.

Comment: I see that you have a good looking example, my compliments on that. But instead of saying what he he should do, could you also explain `why`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya well the idea is that it was coming back from the days of `C` with the stack call frame when you convert what is happening in either `C` or `C++` into stack frames because there is a stack pointer that moves through the stack calls as opposed to heap memory. So yes there are stack or local variables to a specified scope resolution.

Comment: The standard doesn't mention anything about a stack. Yes, most implementations do have a stack and a stack frame for locals. But again, they are implementation details. I would suggest to change stack variables -> locals.

Comment: thanks for your advice Francis Cugler.
 Ajay Brahmakshatriya  thank you and can you explain a bit clearly about the register allocation ???